# How to install custom extension to headless Firefox in Linux?

Tags: firefox, selenium, codeception, headless

Automated tests with Selenium are awesome, but how to do them on headless Firefox with a pre-installed extension?

I found [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions) for Chrome, but nothing for Firefox

How to install an extension to FF?

Comment: Chrome headless doesn't support the extensions, see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the language you are using, but if you have the xpi file handy you can install (or rather enable it like this)

this is a javascript way, but all selenium drivers work the same (look for the profile part)

```js
let binary;
switch (channel) {
    case 'nightly':
    binary = new firefox.Binary(firefox.Channel.NIGHTLY);
    break;
    case 'beta':
    binary = new firefox.Binary(firefox.Channel.BETA);
    break;
    default:
    binary = new firefox.Binary(firefox.Channel.RELEASE);
}

binary.addArguments('-headless');

let options = new firefox.Options();
options.setBinary(binary);

let profile = new firefox.Profile();
profile.addExtension(path.join(__dirname, 'uBlock0@raymondhill.net.xpi'));
options.setProfile(profile);

driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .setFirefoxOptions(options)
    .build();
```

Comment: Oh thanks. But we already migrated to new type of extensions (chrome-compatible), as required for new FF versions. Will check what’s up with tests now. Anyway thanks

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/firefox.js#L29) the link to more details about this API.

Answer (score 0):

now you can install any chrome extension to Firefox. here is the solution.
[How to install chrome extension to firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157086/how-to-install-chrome-extension-to-firefox/47157087#47157087)

Comment: Your link doesn't work any more

Answer (score -1):

You can install add-on globally via command line using (e.g. on my Ubuntu):

```
gksudo firefox -install-global-extension "path_to_your.xpi"
```

Comment: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#Add-ons: "-install-global-extension and -install-global-theme have been removed from Gecko 1.9.2 and upwards."

Gecko 1.9.2 is Firefox 3.6. We are now in Firefox 45.

Answer (score -7):

Best thing is to use some thing like Xvfb . And run firefox in headless mode. http://tobyho.com/2015/01/09/headless-browser-testing-xvfb/

Comment: It's already headless. The question is about installing extensions and not about making it headless. This is not an answer to this question.